# how to parse watch command output to last 5 digits?

Tags: regex, shell, ubuntu, command-line

From the command

```
watch -n1 "ifconfig eth0 | grep GiB"
```

I have output given below,

```
RX bytes:730624111504 (680.4 GiB)  TX bytes:31815434434 (29.6 GiB)
```

Now I just want the last 5 digits before (GiB). I wrote a regex for it, and it seems to [work](http://www.rubular.com/r/fQHTdkCKLI)

```
(\d{1,4})(?!.*\d)\sGiB
```

The only problem is that I cannot use it with the command I showed above.

Any ideas?

Update this is what i want

> RX bytes:730624111504 (680.4 GiB)  TX bytes:31815434434 (29.6 GiB)

to match for RX as

> 4111504 and 5434434

My regex works in http://www.rubular.com/r/HtwFxjCIJm but not in command

Comment: what is your expected output?? `4 and 6`? or what?

Comment: What do you mean "the last 5 digits? `680.4`? `.` isn't a digit. And what about the `29.6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your grep with this one:

```
grep -Po '\d{7}(?=\s*\(.*GiB)'
```

some notes:

- your example shows not **5** digits, but **7**
- You have hardcoded `GiB` in your regex, if your server rebooted, or your network interface down and up, your command may not work properly. because it starts with `KiB or Mib`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the correction, i wanted to know would this command would in real time as well, like i just expect the last 7 changes to appear on the screen?

Comment: if your original one works, this works too. and you can test it. You will see.

Comment: yeah but it failed with -Eo option i think. I will try with -Po now.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

`watch -n1 "ifconfig eth0 | grep GiB | awk '{print substr(\$2, length(\$2) -5), substr(\$6, length(\$6) -5) }'"`

as @Kent pointed out, you can(should) get rid of the grep at this point and only use awk, like this:

`watch -n1 "ifconfig eth0 |  awk '\$0~/GiB/{print substr(\$2, length(\$2) -5), substr(\$6, length(\$6) -5) }'"`

Comment: in 99.99% cases you don't need grep **and** awk

Comment: sounds neat just for info i'm assuming that $2 and $2 are string separated by space (730624111504 and 31815434434) respectively.

Comment: @Kent You are right, but I just build up on the original command. It is fairly trival to remove the grep at this point and add $0~/GiB/{...} to the awk command

Comment: @asadz awk is use the space as the field separator by default so $2 = bytes:730624111504 and $6 = bytes:31815434434

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Ubuntu:

```
echo 'RX bytes:730624111504 (680.4 GiB) TX bytes:31815434434 (29.6 GiB)' |
grep -Po '(\d{7})\s\(.*?GiB\)' | grep -Po '\d{7}'
4111504
5434434
```

Comment: Did u test on live traffic as well? ifconfig